# Determine all values of parameter $p \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the following expression is nonnegative for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality

The expression is
$$x^2 + 8xy + py^2$$
I think that I should complete the square to get something nice to proceed further, but I don't really see the steps to solve this efficiently.

Comment: Hint: complete the square $(x+4y)^2+\cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y) = x^2+8xy+py^2 = (x+4y)^2 +(p-16)y^2\ge 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ if $p - 16 \ge 0$ or $p \ge 16$. For $p < 16$, just pick $x,y$ such that $x+4y = 0, y \neq 0$, then $f(-4y,y) = (p-16)y^2 < 0$.

Comment: you shown only a sufficient condition, you have to exhibit at least one $x,y$ for $p<16$ such that the expression is negative $(-4,1)$ for instance.

Answer (score 2):

If $y=0$ we have $x^2 \ge 0$.

If $y \neq 0$, from the expression we get

$$p \ge -\left( \frac{x}{y}+4  \right)^2+16$$

Therefore $$p \ge max\left( -\left( \frac{x}{y}+4  \right)^2+16 \right)=16$$

This minimum occurs when $x+4y=0$.